# Inserting a new row in vbnet

Tags: mysql, vb.net

is this how i would insert a new person on MYSQL in vb.net

```
Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO login (username, password) VALUES (username ,
 password)", db_con)
```

or is there a better way of doing this.

Comment: Are password and/or username reserved words? If so put them in square brackets

Answer (score 1):

Use parameterized queries to prevent against SQL Injection or even better use a stored procedure.

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text

Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "xyz"
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()


       'Here we execute a command to insert data via stored procedure
        Try
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...")
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn

            cmd.CommandText = "add_emp"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", "Jeremy")
            cmd.Parameters("@uname").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pword", "123abc")
            cmd.Parameters("@pword").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", MySqlDbType.Int32)
            cmd.Parameters("@empno").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Console.WriteLine("Employee number: " & cmd.Parameters("@empno").Value)
        Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
            Console.WriteLine(("Error " & ex.Number & " has occurred: ") + ex.Message)
        End Try
        conn.Close()
        Console.WriteLine("Done.")

    End Sub

End Module

Sub Main()
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;database=world;port=3306;password=******;"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()

    'HERE WE EXECUTE A COMMAND TO CREATE THE TABLE AND STORED PROCEDURE
    Try
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...")
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_emp"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS emp"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE emp (empno INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, user_name VARCHAR(20), password VARCHAR(20))"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE PROCEDURE add_emp(" & "IN uname VARCHAR(20), IN pword VARCHAR(20), OUT empno INT)" & "BEGIN INSERT INTO emp(user_name, password, birthdate) " & "VALUES(uname, pword); SET empno = LAST_INSERT_ID(); END"

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        Console.WriteLine(("Error " & ex.Number & " has occurred: ") + ex.Message)
    End Try
    conn.Close()
    Console.WriteLine("Connection closed.")
End Sub
```

Comment: could you give me a example of how you would write this line of code

Comment: I will post the complete solution shortly, [so] is giving me errors atm trying to post the code ?#$^#$^#?

Comment: I've flagged my post for mod attention, I litrally cant edit it, I keep getting this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171916/an-error-occurred-submitting-the-answer

Comment: i have no idea why it is do that

Comment: I managed to post half of the code and the other half a as picture.

Comment: I could edit the post just fine. Jeremy, can you try again? I put in the code you posted as a screenshot, but I don't know if it's in the right place, etc.

Answer (score 1):

TO prevent from SQL injection you must use parameterized query.I am giving you a refrence of one function, you have to make your function something like that such as

**Insert Function**

```
Public Shared Function InsertFile(ByVal name As String, ByVal pwd As String) As Integer
Dim sql As String
sql = "insert into login (username,password) values (?uname, ?upass);"
Dim params1(2) As MySqlParameter
params1(1) = New MySqlParameter("?uname", name )
params1(2) = New MySqlParameter("?upass", pwd )
Return MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(sql, params1)
End Function
```

Now make a new **ExecuteNonQuery** Function to execute your query

**ExecuteNonQuery Function**

```
Public Shared Function ExecuteNonQuery(ByVal sql As String, ByVal params() As MySqlParameter) As Integer
Dim cnn As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, cnn)
For i As Integer = 0 To params.Length - 1
cmd.Parameters.Add(params(i))
Next
cnn.Open()
Dim retval As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cnn.Close()
Return retval
End Function
```

That's the way, Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO login (username, password) VALUES (? , ?)